# how to get Compared Product collection in magento 2

Tags: magento2, compare

How can I get the Products that are already added in the compare list Product Collection. For Visitor and as well as Login Customer. Can anyone guide me to solutions.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\CustomerData\CompareProducts $compareProducts
) {
    $this->compareProducts = $compareProducts;
}

/*
    * Get current compare product list
    */
public function getCompareList(){
    return $this->compareProducts->getSectionData();
}
```

in **phtml** file,

```
<?php
    $compareObject = $block->getCompareList();
 ?>
<div class="compare-items">
<?php foreach($compareObject['items'] as $comparelist){                        
 ?>
    <div class="compProd">
        <a class="closeComp" data-href="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() ?>ajaxcompare/compare/remove/" data-compare="<?php echo $comparelist['id']; ?>">x</a>
        <span class="gBold cmPrd"><?php echo $comparelist['name']; ?></span>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Will the collection works or both loggin and guest customer.??

Comment: Yes works for both.

Comment: Can I use the above code in controller Will it works? @Rakesh Jesadiya

Comment: Yes you can use in controller also and its works

Comment: Hello @Rakesh I am getting the error when add above code in my controller to fetch collection of compare list as below  https://prnt.sc/jfnw1c

Comment: Please respond to the above reply..

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya i have to use this code but in compare product collection  not working $compareObject['items']

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya i want to checkbox with compare link showing in detail page and same link unchecked than remove it on compare list inside

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya : I have used your code but that is not working on  catalog, cms & product page for me. but for compare page , cart page and checkout page it's working.

Comment: @BalwantSingh. Use this code in controller. In my case, I need compare products count in every page. I use ajax and get the count as well as compare product list.

Answer (score 0):

Inject the following class in the constructor where you want to use it.

> \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Compare\ListCompare

```
public function __construct(
....
....
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Compare\ListCompare $listCompare,
array $data = []
....
) {
...
parent::__construct($context, $data);
$this->listCompare = $listCompare;
...
}
```

2) For getting collection :-

```
$this->listCompare->getItemCollection();
```

Comment: Like if i HAVE ADDED 3 PRODUCT's Already into list then, will i get the count.Here.

Comment: Yes. You can count here.

Comment: When I use your code in my controller i am getting below error as screen shot https://prnt.sc/jfkw3r @Rohan Hapani

Comment: You can use this code where you want to get collection.

Comment: Check my updated answer and use this code.

Comment: Again While running the compile after adding the above code, then iam getting error Incompatible argument type required type :\Magento\Framwork\App\Action\Context. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\view\Element\Template\Context is given @Rohan Hapani

Comment: Did you remove var/ generated/ folder after add this code?

Comment: No I haven't removed the  var/ generated/ folder. is that compulsory. @Rohan Hapani.

Comment: Yes. After inject in construct must be remove var/ and generated/ folder.

Comment: I have removed but also getting same error @Rohan Hapani

Comment: I tried this and it returns all items in compare list collection irrespective what customer is logged in. e.g., in my case it returned 6788 items which were added by all customers.

Comment: @RohanHapani : I have used your code but that is not working on catalog, cms & product page for me in case of guest user. but for compare page , cart page and checkout page it's working. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Compare;

class Count extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
     /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\CustomerData\CompareProducts
     */
    private $_compareProducts;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $jsonHelper;

     /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\CustomerData\CompareProducts $productCompare
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\CustomerData\CompareProducts $compareProducts,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_compareProducts = $compareProducts;
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    }

    /**
     * Check if any item in compare list
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $checkCompare = $params['checkCompare'];
        $isCompare = 0;
        if($checkCompare) {

         /**
          * print_r($this->_compareProducts->getSectionData());
          * You will get all info of compare product
          * I just need count so I have used that only
          */
            
            $isCompare = $this->_compareProducts->getSectionData()['count'];
        }
        return $this->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode($isCompare)
        );
    }
}
```

**compare.phtml file**

```
<?php
$helper = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data');
$isLoggedIn = 0;
if($helper->isLoggedIn()) {
    $isLoggedIn = 1;
}

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui'
    ], function ($) {
        jQuery(document).ready( function() {
            // if any customer is logged in then check compare item count
            var isLoggedIn = '<?php echo $isLoggedIn; ?>';
            isLoggedIn = parseInt(isLoggedIn);
            if(isLoggedIn) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "<?php echo $block->getUrl('frontend_route/controller_name/class_name'); ?>",
                    data : {
                        checkCompare: 1,
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if(data > 0) {
                            $(".compare-signal").show();
                        } else {
                            $(".compare-signal").hide();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $(".compare-signal").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```