# Retrieve Compare Items Collection returning zero Items Magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, compare

While I am trying to return compare items in custom module phtml file, it is returning zero items but in database table catalog_compare_item showing all the added items to compare.

Class Used : `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Compare\ListCompare;`

Block File:

```
     public function __construct(
    ....
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Compare\ListCompare $listCompare,
    array $data = []
    ....
    ) {
    ...
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->listCompare = $listCompare;
    ...
    }

   public function getObj() {
     return $this->listCompare;
   }
```

phtml File:

```
$block->getObj()->getItemCollection();
```

Returning(1000 items where I have added only two products to compare):

```
array(1000) {
  [0]=>
  array(11) {
    ["row_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["entity_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["created_in"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["updated_in"]=>
    string(10) "2147483647"
    ["attribute_set_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["type_id"]=>
    string(6) "simple"
    ["sku"]=>
    string(17) "product_dynamic_1"
    ["has_options"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["required_options"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2018-03-11 07:45:25"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2018-03-11 07:45:25"
  }
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Also, I have tried with class \Magento\Catalog\CustomerData\CompareProducts

Using the method below mention method..
$ClassObj->getSectionData();

Returning:

```
array(4) {
  ["count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["countCaption"]=>
  object(Magento\Framework\Phrase)#1858 (2) {
    ["text":"Magento\Framework\Phrase":private]=>
    string(8) "%1 items"
    ["arguments":"Magento\Framework\Phrase":private]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
  ["listUrl"]=>
  string(100) "http://127.0.0.1/m217ee/catalog/product_compare/index/uenc/aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMS9tMjE3ZWUvbGVhcm4,/"
  ["items"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Try https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/224991/48355

Comment: @PRIENCE - I have tried with this .. But getting result as mentioned below. `array(4) {
  ["count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["countCaption"]=>
  object(Magento\Framework\Phrase)#1265 (2) {
    ["text":"Magento\Framework\Phrase":private]=>
    string(8) "%1 items"
    ["arguments":"Magento\Framework\Phrase":private]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
  ["listUrl"]=>
  string(110) "http://127.0.0.1/mce225/index.php/catalog/product_compare/index/uenc/aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMS9tY2UyMjUvbGVhcm4v/"
  ["items"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}`

Comment: @KausikDey : have you found solution of this problem? I am also facing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$this->listCompare->getItemCollection()` try `$block->getItemCollection()`

if you still face issue post your block code and layout file.

Comment: Hi @rakesh, thanks for replying , I have edited my question, could you please look into it ?