# magento2.4 how to check on listing page if the product is already in compare list or not, or get list of products in compare list?

Tags: magento2, compare

I need to get the know on list page whether the product is already in compare list or not, else get the list of products already in compare list.

I tried the code in below link but getting blank array

```
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224987/how-to-get-compared-product-collection-in-magento-2
```

Can some one please help me on this?

Comment: For compare product collection https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/224991/77554 might help you

Comment: @NileshDubey I tried that but not working